# Switch from Apache to nginx with mod_rewite and htaccess

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, apache2

I Want from Apache to Nginx switch, with mod_rewite and htaccess.
How do I do that?

my mod_rewite set:

```
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /xxxxxx/web/>
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

and my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value mbstring.detect_order       auto
  php_value mbstring.internal_encoding  UTF-8
  php_value mbstring.func_overload      7

  php_value session.gc_probability      1
  php_value session.gc_divisor          100
  php_value session.gc_maxlifetime      1440
</IfModule>

AddType video/x-flv .flv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/ogg .ogg .ogv
AddType video/webm .webm

AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .oga
AddType audio/x-wav .wav

AddType application/pdf .pdf
AddType application/rtf .rtf
AddType text/plain .txt

AddType application/msword .doc
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document .docx
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xls
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet .xlsx
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .ppt
AddType application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation .pptx

AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType application/octet-stream .otf .ttf
AddType application/x-woff .woff
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType application/font-woff .woff

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)(\?.*)?$">
      FileETag All
      Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>

  SetEnvIf Request_URI .*/flashcomm IS_FLASHCOMM
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store" env=IS_FLASHCOMM
      Header unset Expires env=IS_FLASHCOMM
  </IfModule>
  UnsetEnv IS_FLASHCOMM
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript image/png image/gif image/jpeg

  ## Insert filter
  #SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  #
  ## Netscape 4.x has some problems...
  #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  #
  ## Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
  #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  #
  ## MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
  ## BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  #
  ## NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
  ## the above regex won't work. You can use the following
  ## workaround to get the desired effect:
  #BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  #
  #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(og[gav]|mp4|m4[av]|webm|mp3|wav).*$ no-gzip dont-vary
  #
  ## disable gzip compression for media gate
  #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/getMedium/.* no-gzip dont-vary
  #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/cache/.*\.mp4 no-gzip dont-vary
  #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/cache/.*\.m4v no-gzip dont-vary

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # uncomment the following line, if you are having trouble
  # getting no_script_name to work
  #RewriteBase /

  # Backend Application Rules
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend$
  RewriteRule ^backend$ backend.php/ [QSA,L,PT,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/
  RewriteRule ^backend/(.*)$ backend.php/$1 [QSA,L,PT,NC]

  # WebTV Application Rules
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webtv$
  RewriteRule ^webtv$ webtv.php/ [QSA,L,PT,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/webtv/
  RewriteRule ^webtv/(.*)$ webtv.php/$1 [QSA,L,PT,NC]

  # we skip all files with .something
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  #RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+[^/])$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Read documentation on Apache and mod rewrite to understand what the directives you are using do. Search engines are also your friend.
2. Use the nginx documentation to understand how if does the functions that apache/mod rewrite perform. Search engines are also your friend.
3. Build a test environment based on your production environment.
4. Develop a test configuration based on your analysis at 1 and 2 above.
5. Apply the test configuration to the test environment.
6. Test the new configuration
7. Analyse the results of your tests.
8. Repeat 4 to 7 as required to get your configuration correct.
9. Apply the changes to production using your well documented change process.

What not to do.

**1. Dump a bunch of configs on an internet site and hope for the best.**

Comment: Or if some of steps 1-7 fail, post a detailed question on the failed step over here and get help that way. Hiring also some expert on the subject is always an option too.